# Relative version of sheaf cohomology?

Tags: cohomology, sheaf-theory

Is there a relative version of sheaf cohomology?
EDIT: I rather mean the cohomology of pairs.

Comment: Yes (in algebraic geometry, at least): the derived functors of the pushforward functor from sheaves on the top the to sheaves on the bottom.


Comment: Let's make sure we are talking about the same thing. The word `relative' has (at least) two meanings:

- (AG meaning) defined for families: this leads to derived direct images;

- (topological meaning) defined for pairs: this leads to cohomology with support.

Which one are we talking about here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that my previous answer dealt with the wrong question.  The answer to the
new question is also yes:
local cohomology $H\_Z(X,\mathcal F)$ corresponds to cohomology of the pair $(X,X\setminus Z)$.

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I want to understand the local cohomology and look for a more 'geometrical' definition. Do you know of a good text on local cohomology where this correspondence is treated? 

Comment: One basic text is (if I remember correctly) the Springer Lecture Notes
<I>Local cohomology</I> by Hartshorne (it's early in the series, maybe
in the first 100), based on lectures of Grothendieck.  But it is focused on algebraic geometry.  There are some texts on sheaf theory
that are more focussed on the usual (rather than Zariski) topology,
e.g.  Borel's <I> Intersection homology </I>.  Verdier duality is treated in that book, I think, which generalizes Poincare and Alexander-Lefschetz duality, so at least implicity it should treat
this correspondence.

Comment: One could also consult the references in Borel and see where they lead.   

Local cohomology also plays an important role in Sato's theory of hyperfunctions (which is treated in one or more Springer Lecture Notes volumes, among other places).  Maybe looking at that literature would give an interesting perspective.  

Some of Kashiwara's books on sheaf theory might also help (and they probably have overlap with the books already mentioned).  

I'm sorry not to be able to give more specific references.  Maybe someone else can?  

Comment: This overlaps somewhat with Matt's answer, but SGA2 also has a nice and comprehensive discussion of local cohohomology and its various incarnations in topology, algebraic geometry, and commutative algebra, and relations among all three. The book of Freitag-Kiehl on etale cohomology discuss the analogous theory in that setting, including various important/useful "purity theorems" when Z sits nicely inside a nice X.

Answer (score 17):

To elaborate on Kevin's comment: If $f: X \to S$, and $\mathcal F$ is a sheaf on
$X$, then $f\_*\mathcal F$ is the sheaf on $S$ defined by $H^0(U,f\_*\mathcal F)
:= H^0(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal F).$

Taking the derived functors of $f\_*$ gives functors $R^if\_*$, and it turns out
(fairly easily) that $R^if\_*(\mathcal F)(U)$ is the sheaf associated to the presheaf
$U \mapsto H^i(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal F)$.  If $i > 0,$ then this presheaf may not be
a sheaf (unlike the $i = 0$ case), and this is related to the fact that it can be a little subtle to compute the stalks of $R^if\_*\mathcal F$ in general; for example, it need not
be the case in general that the stalk $(R^if\_*\mathcal F)_s$ is equal to
$H^i(f^{-1}(s),\mathcal F)$.  (E.g. think about the case when $f$ is the inclusion of
a punctured disk into a disk, $\mathcal F$ is the constant sheaf ${\mathbb Z}$,
and $s$ is the centre of the disk (so that $f^{-1}(s)$ is empty).)

In other words, $R^if\_*\mathcal F$ does not always literally interpolate the cohomology
of the fibres.

There is one case where one knows that $R^if\_*\mathcal F$  *does*  interpolate
the cohomology of the fibres: if the map $f$ is proper, than the proper base-change theorem
says that the stalk of $R^if\_*\mathcal F$ at $s$ is the cohomology of $\mathcal F$ along
the fibre of $s$. (One good place for these kinds of facts is the beginning of Borel's book on Intersection Cohomology.)

Also, in the context of maps of varieties, if $f$ is proper and $\mathcal F$ is a coherent
sheaf, then the completed stalk of $R^if\_* \mathcal F$ at $s$ coincides with the cohomology
of the pull-back of $\mathcal F$ to the formal completion of $f^{-1}(s)$ in $X$. (This is Grothendieck's proper base-change theorem, proved in some form in Hartshorne, Ch. III.)

Answer (score 3):

I would think -- but this is for the moment a thought, not meant as an authoritative answer -- that *every* notion of cohomology whatsoever has a relative version in this sense.

I am thinking here of the general abstract definition of cohomology as exposed at [nLab:cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohomology).
This includes in particular the special case of [sheaf cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/abelian+sheaf+cohomology) as described there in some detail.

What I expect the fully general notion of relative cohomology from this point of view to be I have now briefly indicated at [relative cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relative+cohomology). I'd believe this does in particular reproduce the definition given in Emerton's answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the current answers are sort of alluding to the following, but not saying it explicitly.

In any setup where you have the six functors (de Rham, Betti = sheaves of vector spaces on topological spaces, $\ell$-adic cohomology,... ) and $i:Z\to X$ is a closed embedding, then the local cohomology is defined as
$$\mathcal{H}_Z(X,\mathcal{F})\ =\ \text{H}^*(Z,i^!\mathcal{F})$$
so we have an analogue of $\text{H}^*(X,X\setminus Z)$ for any of your favourite cohomology theories ([or others like stable homotopy theory, algebraic cobordism, K theory, Chow, ...](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02145) ). Then using all the properties of the six functors (Gysin sequence etc), you get the standard e.g. long exact sequences involving local/relative cohomology.

Comment: But local cohomology does exist in the quasi-coherent context.

Comment: @LeoAlonso Thanks, I wasn't thinking- edited that bit out! All I meant is that you cannot use this six functor definition as far as I know.

Comment: I am not sure how you view six functors, but $D_Z(X)\to D(X)\to D(X\setminus Z)$ is a split Verdier sequence when, say, the ideal sheaf of $Z$ is finitely generated.